# 'examples' in matplotlib documentation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Many matplotlib function doc pages (e.g. `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`) give a reference to an example *somewhere*, e.g.

```
[...]
Examples
--------
.. plot:: mpl_examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.py
```

If I'm using ipython, is there an easy way to look at these examples?

Comment: `matplotlib` is open source, see e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.py

Answer (score 0):

All the examples are on the website.
For the example you mentioned:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.html

You can see the list of examples here:
http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

you can `%load` files in IPython, and if the filename starts with "http://" it will load the URL.

They call them magic commands for a reason!